# Why is my import command not working even though I used the pip command?

Tags: python, import, pip

I try to import a "rotate screen" function, and python just says it doesnt exist, even though I used the "pip" command in the terminal.

What I tried:

import rotate_screen

What Happened:

Import "rotate_screen" could not be resolved

Comment: Can you add a complete code example please?

Comment: @cvk yeah its there under the "what I tried" and "What Happened" section

Comment: If you installed https://pypi.org/project/rotate-screen/, it looks like there is no underscore `import rotatescreen`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the module you're trying to import may not be installed correctly. Make sure you've installed it using "**pip install rotate-screen**" in your terminal. Also, double-check the correct name of the module, It should be "**import rotatescreen**". you need to remove the "_" from your import statement.